# Open a Fragment from preferences.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I've got an android app which has a Fragment and preferences.xml.  I'm having a difficult time getting the fragment to open from a menu item in preferences.xml

Here are the relevant bits:

preferences.xml

```
<PreferenceScreen
android:key="pref_mypref"
android:title="My Pref"
android:persistent="false"
android:fragment="com.mypackage.MyFragment">
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Is it possible to open a fragment from a preferences screen item like this?

Comment: Good question with no answer for 5 years and counting. Seemingly the the Fragment must be started by a dummy activity started via `<intent android:action="..." />`